# Can't find variable: token

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Im trying to get data from an endpoint API with axios but there is this error: Cant find token, can you please help me?? This is my code, the first file is request and the second file is the code where im trying to get data.

**request file:**

```
import axios from "axios"

let axiosApiInstance = axios.create();

function setToken(token,RefreshToken) {
    
    axios.defaults.headers.common['x-access-token'] = token;

    axiosApiInstance.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
        return response
      }, async function (error) {
        const originalRequest = error.config;
        if (error.response.status === 401 && !originalRequest._retry) {
          originalRequest._retry = true;           
          axios.defaults.headers.common['x-refresh-token'] = RefreshToken;
          return axiosApiInstance(originalRequest);
        }
        return Promise.reject(error);
      });
   
}

export default {
    get: axios.get,
    post: axios.post,
    delete: axios.delete,
    put: axios.put,
    setToken: setToken,
}
```

**this is the code im using to get data in a screen**

```
useEffect(() => {
    getData();
    return () => {};
  }, []);

  const getData = async () => {
    request
      .get("http://18.156.84.96:5000/api/client/orders/get-orders/1/Active", {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `${token}`,
        },
      })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  };
```

Comment: token isn't available in the useEffect function. You should modify setToken to set Authorization header by default or provide to the input of the second function.

Answer (score 0):

Modify setToken function to set token in the following way:

```
// Add a request interceptor
axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
    config.headers.Authorization =  token;

    return config;
});
```

And remove headers objects from the get request, as token isn't available here

Comment: What about the refresh token in a setToken function, cause i need that too